# sql creating table issue

Tags: sql

unexpected beginning of statement

[the coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIKRw.png)

Comment: Could you please clarify what RDBMS and DB-client you use

Comment: Please share more details, like the query you are using and the error message you are facing

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the CREATE TABLE statement as text and not as an image. That makes it easier for me to copy and test your code. Maybe it's time you took the [tour]?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL then the issue is with create query where you passes int(10)

you can not pass any size to int type of fields

```
create table acc
(acc_id int not null primary key,
username_acc varchar(30) not null,
....)
```

Try with above
Thanks

Comment: "*If you are using SQL*" - apparently he is. SQL is not a specific database product, it's a query language used by all relational databases.